# Fixed size log file containing only the most recent entries

Tags: java, debugging, logging, netbeans, file-io

I have a bug that is guaranteed to happen if the program runs long enough (more than an hour.)

The only way to solve this is to print a massive amount of debugging information, which unfortunately is growing at a rate of 1MB/s!

Though util.Logging.FileHandler has the option to set the size limit of the log files, it simply erases the files and write from scratch once the limit is reached.

Is there a way to write to a log file in a "rolling" manner, such that on exceeding size limit, newest entries displace oldest ones instead of wiping everything out? Currently, I juggle among the log files, but it can get confusing.

Thank you!

Comment: I assume you have tried http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=rolling+logger+java

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes I have. However, most people go with the creation of multiple fixed size logs, which is what I currently have. It would be nice to have one continuously rolling file. :D

Comment: You cannot remove from the start of a file because the OS doesn't support that.  You can only append to the end of a file. Having rolling files is your only option. (This is not a limitation of Java but the OS)

Answer (score 0):

Can you use or have you considered using [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/index.html)??

Search for 'RollingFileAppender' in the [manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html). Playing with its 'MaxFileSize' and 'MaxBackupIndex' properties should do the trick!